# Is there any way one can solve a tangram with n pieces effectively

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

I suppose that everyone here has played with a tangram, whether fun of not, solving a tangram could be puzzling. I guess most of you are playing with a 7 piece tangram. And to be honest, a 7 piece tangram is challenging enough to take me like 3 to 4 minutes to solve. Here is my question, may be considering it as a generalization of a tangram, How can one solve a n-piece tangram effectively? By n piece tangram, I mean a square cut with a number of straight lines to separate it into n pieces.

Comment: This feels like it could be an NP-hard problem. That is, even an efficient algorithm may grow exponentially with the number of pieces.

Comment: It is perhaps straight line *segments* that are used to cut the pieces?  Restricting to cuts along straight lines (all the way through the original square) probably creates easier problems.

Comment: I once gave programming a puzzle placement problem thought.  The hard part lay in breaking it into a finite number of finite choices, but one starting point is in a corner, getting the pieces that can fill up a right angle.